# Copy files which do not exist in log file to folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

Essentially I need to be able to copy new files from the source folder which were not present the last time the script ran to a destination folder.

Here is what I am thinking:

-Script to run every 1 min
-Source Folder
-Destination Folder
-Log file records file which was copied

Process:

-Run through directory file by file and check against log file to determine if file needs to be copied.

-If file exists in log file DO NOT COPY

-If file DOES NOT EXIST in log file, Copy to Destination Folder, Write filepath/filename to logfile

-Continue to next file in directory

This is what I have but am experiencing issues with findstr and not entirely sure this is the best way to go about it.

```
@echo off
:start

for /r "C:\Source" %%i in (*) do (

    echo --------------------------------------
    echo Searching for: %%i
    type log.txt | findstr /L "%%i"

    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 ( 
    echo NOT FOUND
    goto copyfile 
    )
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( 
        echo FOUND
    )
echo ------------------------------------------

:copyfile 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Copy %%i
copy "%%i" C:\Destination
echo Writing to log file: %%i
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------
echo %%i >> log.txt

)
```

I would greatly appreciate the insight. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You are trying to replicate in batch code part of the functions of `robocopy`. Any reason not to use it?

Comment: You sir, Deserve a trophy!! That is perfect and exactly what I need. 1 line of code to do it all!! Also used NSSM to wrap the bat as a service. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

As *MC ND* pointed out RoboCopy is the answer and certainly worked for me.

```
robocopy source-path destination-path /r:30 /w:20 /mon:1 /mot:1 /log+: path-to-log
```

/r:30 - Retries to copy 30 times if copy error occurs
/w:20 - Waits 20 seconds before retrying copy
/mon:1 - Monitors source directory for a change of 1 file
/mot:1 - Waits 1 minute before checking for changes
/log+: - Appends to log file

To see more info on Robocopy in cmd type robocopy /?